# Unsupported file format when call AudioFileStreamParseBytes with m4a file bytes

Tags: objective-c, ios7, audio-streaming, m4a

I'm using this tutorial: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity. It works nicely for MP3 files, but not with other formats.

Checking the library, I found that calling `AudioFileStreamParseBytes()` (in order to decode the received bytes) fails with all formats except with MP3 bytes.

In the [library reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/musicaudio/reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioFileStreamParseBytes), it says this supports:

> AIFF, AIFC, WAVE, CAF, NeXT, ADTS, MPEG Audio Layer 3, AAC.

I was trying with clean AAC, but it was still not working, giving the same error: `not supported file type`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you got any idea how this is possible ? i am kinda stuck in the same case scenario

Comment: Hi, I am facing same problem? @Gonzalo Bahamondez, do you get any workaround?